# How to horizontally center text without knowing the width of the .div

Tags: html, css, text, center

I am making a grid to show products in. The grid is built up with several divs in a row with width set in percentages. Is it possible to center the text horizontally without changing the way the divs have been set up?

All suggestions are very welcome!

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container21-b">
    <div class="blok21-a">
        </a> <a class="text-container-price"> € 29,95 </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
 .container21-a {
    position: relative;
    height: 155px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 12.95714%;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 1.55%;
}
.container21-b {
    position: relative;
    height: 155px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 12.95714%;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.blok21-a {
    position: relative;
    height: 155px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
.blok21-a:hover {
    position: relative;
    height: 155px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
.text-container-price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font: Verdana;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    ;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/eBeZ3/)**

Comment: JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/eBeZ3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `text-align:center;`

```
.blok21-a {
   position: relative;
   height: 155px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   background-color:#f9f9f9;
   text-align:center; /* <------ */
}
```

here is working version: http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/PRjU5/

Comment: Accepted the answer;)